# Win32 class property data type mismatch error

Tags: c#, windows, windows-7, device-manager

I'm trying to set a new value to the "InstallDate" property of class `Win32_NetworkAdapter`.

here is a link to a description of the class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Yet, when I'm trying to set a new DateTime, I get a "type mismatch" error, even though I'm trying to set a DateTime object like listed in the struct.

this is the code:

```
private static void Check()
{
  var win32DeviceClassName = "Win32_NetworkAdapter";
  var query = string.Format("select * from {0}", win32DeviceClassName);

  using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
  {
    ManagementObjectCollection objectCollection = searcher.Get();

    foreach (ManagementBaseObject managementBaseObject in objectCollection)
    {
      if (!managementBaseObject.Properties["Description"].Value.ToString().Contains("what i need"))
      {
        continue;
      }
      managementBaseObject.Properties["InstallDate"].Value = DateTime.Now;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok I didn't notice that somehow... But then how do you actually do see a value in the install date property? When you open the device manager and choose a device you can see a value in the install date property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question has the answer, if you go through the documentation it says

> InstallDate
>
> Data type: datetime
>
> Access type: Read-only
>
> Date and time the object was installed. This property does not need a value to indicate that the object is installed. This property is inherited from CIM_ManagedSystemElement.
> This property has not been implemented yet. It returns a NULL value by default.

Comment: Ok I didn't notice that somehow... But then how do you actually do see a value in the install date property? When you open the device manager and choose a device you can see a value in the install date property

Comment: system will be setting it internally